# Better method to create an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> I want to create an array of numbers. I have used two methods but first one is not creating a new array of numbers. I want to know why is the first method is not working ?

```
var arr = [];
      var i;
      for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
      var new_array = arr.push(i);   
}
    console.log(Array.isArray(new_array));

> Output : false

     var i;
        for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
        var arr = new Array(i)
 }
       console.log(Array.isArray(arr));



> Output: true
```

Comment: Obviously, `new_array ` is not declared as an array

Comment: How is it not declared as an Array.

Comment: `var new_array = arr.push(i);` will hold length of array after pushing the element, not whole array

Answer (score 1):

Because `push` returns the new length of the array, it'll be `1`, `2`, `3`, etc., but if you do `console.log(Array.isArray(arr));` after the loop, it'll show `true`. Basically, the array you're creating in your first example is stored in `arr` rather than `new_array`.

Comment: `Array.prototype.push` returns the new length of the modified array.

Comment: Whoops, was thinking of like `pop` I think @GerardoFurtado. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

In fist method you are assigning value to new_array variable. Every time for loop executes that time new value is assigning to this variable. That's why first method is not working